Have any abstractionists discussed the possibility of multiple abstraction principles?
An abstractionist is someone who claims that some version of Frege's abstraction principle accounts for or justifies talk of abstract objects. The abstraction principle says that an equation of the form

f(x)=f(y) <=> x~y

justifies talk of objects like f(x) based on an equivalence relation x~y. For example, let d(x) be the direction of line x. What is a direction? Well it is defined using the parallel relation as follows:

d(x)=d(y) <=> x||y

So the fundamental objects are line and the relation of being parallel, and directions are derived from that base, along with all of the properties of directions.
All of the abstractionists I've read (Frege, Wright and Linnebo are the only ones that come to mind, but I've read others) seem to take that specific equation form as fundamental and consider no others, but what about Whitehead's extensive abstraction based on the limit of a sequence? Whitehead abstraction can be used to justify abstractions that are hard to do with Frege abstraction; for example, the abstraction of a geometric point or an ideal gas or a completed infinity. And then there is what we might call a Hilbert abstraction, namely just the existence of an abstract object that answers to any formal theory.
My impression is that the abstractionist program could be fruitfully extended by including these and other sorts of object-forming formalisms in addition to Frege's abstraction principle, but I've never seen a discussion of it. The closest I've seen is a paper by Wright where he contrasts Frege abstraction and Hilbert abstraction as if they were competitors and mutually exclusive.

Neo-Fregeans are not really after a rich account of abstraction. Their drive is the opposite, to augment logic minimally, enough for the result to serve as a foundation of mathematics. What you suggest is more in the spirit of non-eliminative structuralism where all sorts of "placeholders in a structure" are treated as objects. Linnebo and Pettigrew discuss how Frege and Dedekind abstraction principles are not up to the task of structuralists' designs.

@Conifold, in my understanding, structuralists are OK with identifying abstract objects with any suitable model, whereas abtractionists identify them with the minimal object satisfying some condition. That is, a structuralist is happy equating the natural numbers with a sequence of sets but an abstractionist would say that 0 is no more the empty set than it is Julius Cesar. Also, the abstractionist account of abstract objects is closely associated with neo-Fregeanism, but new-Fregeanism is a larger thing.

As I understand it, non-eliminative structuralists like Shapiro do not equate numbers with any realization. Morally, there supposed to be a unique "pure structure" with elements abstracted to have no "non-structural" properties, and those are the numbers. As Linnebo-Pettigrew describe it:"A pure structure is the result of some operation of abstraction on a class of systems that are pairwise isomorphic. We call its elements positions. It is the operation of abstraction that is applied to a system to give a pure structure that is our topic here."

@Conifold I'd love to read that paper but I no longer have access to a university library.
